# Is JWT signed by Keycloak when provided by a client with access type public?

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I have a Keycloak 7.0 server. Users of my application authenticate using a client with access type public, then they receive a bearer token JWT to use in subsequent requests to a bearer-only client. Is this JWT signed (perhaps by something at the realm level) in any way?

I am attempting to implement a back end service (JHipster/Spring Security) that requires a JWT secret to validate requests - and have found nothing that works for this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes keycloak will add a signature in JWT token using its private key. You can verify that token by using subsequent public key.

You can get public key by calling https:///auth/realms//protocol/openid-connect/certs

Comment: From this route I get a json with keys: kid, kty, alg, use, n, e, x5c, x5t, and x5t#S256 . Is the value I am looking for x5c (my guess based on the values)? When inserting this value as my jwt secret on my server I get the following response from a request: Invalid JWT token. Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource.

Comment: _Edit: On jwt.io it appears to say my signature is valid so I suspect this is the correct value_

Comment: n field is the public key. I also have the invalid signature issue.